# Can I buy in Japan expensive thing and transfer it to third party country through South Korea without paying taxes in Korea?

Tags: japan, south-korea, taxes, tax-refunds

I want to travel (Russia -> Japan -> South Korea -> Russia). I want to buy a laptop in Japan ($4300). Should I pay taxes on South Korea border when I will enter/leave country?

Comment: Are you transiting through South Korea? Or staying for a few days or more? Are your flights on one ticket?

Comment: I want to stay on 4 nights in Seoul

Comment: Aside from the question of possible import duties, buying something like a laptop in one country for use in another country is potentially a problem: it will probably come preinstalled with an OS configured in Japanese and with a Japanese keyboard.  The power plug won't fit your local electrical outlets and the power adaptor might not work with your voltage.  And the warranty might not be valid should anything go wrong with your high-end laptop.  You might consider investigating these issues before purchasing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found answer:

According of Korean customs site:

http://www.customs.go.kr/kcshome/cop/bbs/selectBoardList.do?bbsId=BBSMSTR_1779&layoutMenuNo=32094&siteId=english&currentPageNo=1&searchWrd=certificate+for+temporarily+admitted+goods+on+the+condition+of+re-exportation&x=32&y=13

The way to report temporarily admitted goods on the condition of re-exportation

```
A 'certificate for temporarily admitted goods on the condition of re-exportation' needs to be submitted to the head of a customhouse, which is provided by the customs authority at the time of entry. Where it is not possible to provide a domestic address and contact information, goods can be temporarily admitted by providing security.



When exiting the country, it is required to submit the 'certificate for temporarily admitted goods on the condition of re-exportation' issued by the head of a customhouse to a customs official, and the goods need to be carried out within a year when exiting the country for the first time.



Failure to carry out the goods or to carry out the goods without reporting will result in payment of the total taxes including the customs duty and additional 20% of the total taxes. Where the goods are intentionally not carried out, the person may be punished for violation of the Customs Act.



Further information can be found on the 'certificate for temporarily admitted goods on the condition of re-exportation'.
```

Comment: I expect that applies to persons on students and work visas more than tourists. Millions of tourists are crossing borders every day with laptops and no particular attention from customs, although your laptop is pretty high-end. Assuming you are planning to use the laptop, it's a personal effect.

Comment: Hi, Andrew! Thank you. It is just my first trip abroad, so I a little bit excited and nervous :)